# Discrepancy in formula for sum of powers of reciprocals of roots

Tags: complex-analysis

If $f$ is a polynomial with distinct, non-zero roots, it immediately follows that 
$$\frac{\rm d}{{\rm d} x}\log f(x)=\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=\sum_{r\in\text{roots}}\frac1{x-r}.$$
By expanding each summand as a geometric series and grouping the like powers of $x$, you get a nice formula for the sums of powers of reciprocals of the roots
$$-\frac{\rm d}{{\rm d} x}\log f(x)=\sum\frac1r+\;x\sum \frac1{r^2}+\;x^2\sum\frac1{r^3}+\cdots.$$
In other words, the coefficients of the Taylor series of $-\frac{\rm d}{{\rm d} x}\log f(x)$ give the sums of the powers of the reciprocals of the roots of $f$. This formula has been around a long time, probably since Newton.

Since it works for polynomials, surely (?!) the formula works for more general classes of functions. For instance, the roots of $\frac{\sin x}x$ are $\pi n $ for $n\in\mathbb{Z}-\{0\}$, and the coefficients of the Taylor series of  $-\frac{\rm d}{{\rm d} x}\log \frac{\sin x}x$ and the sums $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}-\{0\}}\frac{1}{(\pi n)^k}$ turn out to agree (at least Maple thinks so).

The formula *mainly* works for functions involving exponentials. As examples,  $\frac{{\rm e}^x-1}{x}$ has  roots at $2\pi i n$ for $n\in\mathbb{Z}-\{0\}$, and ${\rm e}^x-2$ has  roots at $\log(2)+2\pi i n$ for $n\in \mathbb Z$. Experimentation in Maple seems to show that
$$-[x^k]\frac{\rm d}{{\rm d} x}\log \frac{{\rm e}^x-1}x= \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}-\{0\}}\frac1{(2\pi i n)^{k+1}}$$
and $$-[x^k]\frac{\rm d}{{\rm d} x}\log({\rm e}^x-2)= \sum_{n\in \mathbb Z}\frac1{(\log(2)+2\pi i n)^{k+1}} $$
*as long as* $k\ge1$. However, in both cases a discrepancy of $\frac12$ arises between the constant term of the Taylor series and the sum of the (first powers of) the reciprocals of the roots. In particular,
$$-[x^0]\frac{\rm d}{{\rm d} x}\log \frac{{\rm e}^x-1}{x}=-\frac12\quad\text{ but }\quad\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}-\{0\}}\frac1{2\pi i n}=0$$
and
$$-[x^0]\frac{\rm d}{{\rm d} x}\log({\rm e}^x-2)=1\quad\text{ but }\quad\sum_{n\in \mathbb Z}\frac1{\log(2)+2\pi i n}=\frac 32.$$

Questions:

1. What went wrong in the calculations of the constant coefficients and sums of reciprocals of roots in the examples with the exponential functions?
2. Are there well-known conditions that ensure the original formula works for *all* coefficients?

Comment: Note: The sums are not absolute convergent.

Comment: If $f$ is entire  and $ \sum_k \frac{1}{z-r_k} $ converges then $\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)} =h(z)+ \sum_k \frac{1}{z-r_k} $ for some entire function $h$. For the trigonometric functions, the game is to show $h$ is bounded [so it is constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(complex_analysis)). See also Weiestrass factorization theorem for entire functions of order $1$. In particular for $f(z) = \frac{d}{dz}\log \frac{e^z-1}{z}$ you should obtain $h(z) = -1/2$